# How do I place two embedded links next to each other on my website?

Tags: html, github

I'm using GitHub Pages to host my own website, a basic personal portfolio. On my homepage, I've put in my twitter feed of my tweets, and then another feed of my likes. These embedded objects show up beneath each other, but I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to place them next to each other on the page. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set absolute positions for each of the iframes.